# Connecting to oracle DB through python

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to an oracle db using python through PyCharm, below is my code and a screenshot of the connection details

**Code:**

```py
import cx_Oracle   
try:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('sys/123@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1')    
except:
    print("Connection Error")
    exit()
```

**Output**

Connection Error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that, either with SID or service name

**SID :**

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', 'sid')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='password', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

**Service name :-**

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', service_name='service_name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='password', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

You can refer to this documentation [HERE](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html)

Comment: Thanks! it worked. However, I faced another error ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

Comment: this is how I wrote it: tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn("localhost","1521", service_name="XEPDB1")
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="sys", password="123", dsn=tns)

Comment: Regarding connecting as SYSDBA, search the doc link in the answer for the syntax to use: `mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA`.  A general note: Avoid using SIDs; their use was obsoleted a decade or more ago.

Answer (score 0):

For new versions:

```
import oracledb

conn = oracledb.connect(user='sys', password='pass', dsn='localhost:1521/database', mode=oracledb.SYSDBA)
```

for normal users use: mode=oracledb.AUTH_MODE_DEFAULT